# Is it possible to convert PHP(require) to perl?

Tags: php, perl, include

I mainly use Perl, and lately Ive started to learn some PHP.
So would it be possible to convert this to Perl?

```
<?php  
 require("common.php"); 
 if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) { 
   header("Location: login.php"); 
   die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
 }     
?>
```

Though, if I'm not mistaken, will "`common.php`" have to be made into a Perl cgi page aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use require in perl.. just require the .pl or .cgi..

```
 require './yourscriptlib.pl'

 dosomestufffromyourscriptlib.pl();
```

just remember the script will execute when required.. just as any other script.

Comment: note that this is a pretty unusual pattern in Perl; usually you want to write your shared code as modules and then `use` them.

Comment: Not necessarily.. we have a large web app with shared libraries of code and we just require them..